# hide body until external resources(loaded asynchronously) load

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, loading

So, I have various external resources like google material icons and so on which are loaded using the `link` and `script` tags:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

How can I hide the `body` until all these resources(loaded via `link` and `script`) are loaded completely? Can I do this using custom directives? And also, *I am NOT using jQuery*.

**EDIT:**

The reason I want this is that google's material design icons are included in the following way:

```
<i class="material-icons">
    visibility
</i>
```

So, while the material icons css is still loading, I can see all these icon texts, 'visibility' in my case on the screen in their textual form. And, only when the css loads, does the text translate to icon form. I'll add a screenshot soon.

Comment: stylesheets fonts are always loaded before contents are shown. Actually people are struggling to find a way to make content shown *before* font files are loaded, which is the reverse of what you're asking...

Comment: I have edited the question to explain why I want it to be the way I am asking.

Comment: @TarunDugar  In response to your edit, if your body has `display: none`, `visibility` of any element is a moot point. As long as the body is in that state, it's children are as well.

Comment: yes as long as it is none, its ok. BUT when it gets visible, and the external resource hasn't loaded yet, I experience the problem mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Hide your body in our CSS, and show it when the event DOMContentLoaded is triggered

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     document.body.style.display = 'block';
  });
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't be needed if placed at the closing tag of body.

Answer (score 0):

Just add display:none for body tag in header :-

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            body{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>

        /* Load all your external CSS and JS */
    </head>
    <body>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(body).css("display", "block");
            })
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It may help you.

Comment: As I mentioned, no jQuery. And I am loading my JS at the end of my body tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2**

OP's issue concerning loading external scripts *may need* further testing with `async` and `defer` attributes. The following links will help in that direction:

- [Async and Defer (non-blocking JavaScript with HTML5)](http://cristian.sulea.net/blog/async-and-defer-non-blocking-javascript-with-html5/)
- [JavaScript Execution Order; Asynchronous JavaScript](http://xahlee.info/js/js_executing_order.html)
- [Promises - Thinkster](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/promises)
- [In 3 Minutes, JavaScript Loading of Scripts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlkHxjTrmqs)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)
- [Deep dive into the murky waters of script loading](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

---

Here's the JS equivalent of Harsh's code (if placed at the closing `</body>` tag):

**EDIT 1**

`delayedBy(ms)` is triggered by the `onload` event of `<body>`. You can adjust the delay.

```js
function delayedBy(ms) {
  setTimeout('visible()', ms);
}

function visible() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  body.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
body {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body onload="delayedBy(1000);">
  <h1>Here I am!</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: not working, the document gets loaded, but the external resources are still being loaded(as it is an async process) after the body gets visible.

Comment: Ah, async, ok, then apply `visibility: hidden` instead and timeout a function to bring body back in.

Comment: timeout on what? How do I know when the external resource will be loaded? Is there a way I can have a callback to a resource being loaded completely?

Comment: See update, I'd have to research about that. My site generates pages by AJAX and 1 sec (1000ms) is overkill.

Comment: Ok, really appreciate your help! Let me try it.

Comment: So, this is just delaying the visibility by 1 sec. What if my resource takes more time to load?

Comment: `<body onload="delayBy(1750);">` that would be 1.75 seconds. Adjust accordingly. Does your resources take longer to load? If so, you'll need to use a combination of `async` and `defer` attributes on your external `<script> tags. I'll post the links on my answer, but I can't really give you concrete details since I don't know full details of your setup nor do I have access. Fortunately you do, links posted shortly, good luck too you, and please post findings because loading JS is a murky subject.

Answer (score 0):

Using this: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader
Will output a class to HTML tag while loading fonts, this way:

```
.wf-loading
.wf-active
.wf-inactive
.wf-<familyname>-<fvd>-loading
.wf-<familyname>-<fvd>-active
.wf-<familyname>-<fvd>-inactive
```

With that you can do anything from html >  to any other tag, body for example, so:

```
.wf-loading body{display:none;}
.wf-active body{display:block;}
```

Also you have callbacks to use via js, take a look, it´s working: http://fiddle.jshell.net/m2d6k8er/ it´s just a very basic example of course.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.